# how to use `yy_scan_string(const char *str)` (generated by lex yacc ) in a separated file

Tags: c++, redirect, bison, yacc, lex

I want to use `YY_BUFFER_STATE yy_scan_string(const char *str)` and other functions like `yyparse()` in my `main.cpp`, I did things:

```
extern "C"{
extern YY_BUFFER_STATE yy_scan_string(const char *str);
}
```

But there is a error `error:`YY_BUFFER_STATE' does not name a type`, then I did:

```
extern yy_buffer_state;
typedef yy_buffer_state *YY_BUFFER_STATE;
extern int yyparse();
extern YY_BUFFER_STATE yy_scan_buffer(char *, size_t);
```

But the same problem also, how to do it, thanks, really appreciate your help!!

Here is the main.cpp file.
     #include "main.h"

```
 #include <string.h>
 extern "C"{void scan_string(const char* str);}
 int yyparse();
 void test::getvalue(int& var)
 {
    if (var!=0)
        std::cout<<"True"<<std::endl;
    else
        std::cout<<"False"<<std::endl;
  }

  int main(){
     std::string str="T+F";
     //how to send str as an Input to parse?

     yyparse();
     return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Paste the upper portion of your main.c file

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution is probably to add a separate function in your grammar file that in turn call `yy_scan_string`.

```
/* Stuff... */

%%

/* Grammar */

%%

void scan_string(const char* str)
{
    yy_switch_to_buffer(yy_scan_string(str));
}
```

Then call `scan_string` from your code.

Comment: How to fix it, actually, I just put as your suggestion.

Comment: Maybe you should show us a bit more of your code, and what you're doing when you get that error. Seems to me like you most probably have some other syntax error in your file.

Comment: good, put the function in the **.y file, and call it in the **.cc file, avoid direct call in .cc file.